# Task custom condition: does a given file exist?

Tags: azure-devops

## What I'm trying to do

I have a task to execute that only makes sense if a certain config file exists. So I want to put a custom condition on the task that returns `true` if that file exists. I imagine a syntax like this would make sense:

```
condition: exists('$(projectPath)\myconfigfile.xml')
```

This seems like a reasonable use case for custom conditions.

## What Microsoft documents

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions

Microsoft says the following functions are always available: `and`, `coalesce`, `contains`, `endsWith`, `eq`, `format`, `ge`, `gt`, `in`, `le`, `lt`, `ne`, `not`, `notIn`, `or`, `startsWith`, `xor`. And furthermore:

[image: "Depending on context, other functions may be available..."]

## My actual question

I'm finding this a little frustrating. What "other functions" are there? How can I research them? And in particular, is there one that takes a filename and tells me if that file exists?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no built in condition or function that operates off of the presence or absence of a file.

You can write and run a script that sets a variable, then check the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 77):

Daniel's answer is correct so just to provide an example:

Create a PowerShell task to set the pipeline variable:

```
$fileExists = Test-Path -Path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/file.txt"
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FileExists]$fileExists"
```

Create a secondary task that uses the variable in a custom condition:

```
eq(variables['FileExists'], True)
```

Comment: Maybe you'll know this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77468415/azure-custom-task-visiblerule-definition-error

Answer (score -6):

This trick worked for me, just copy the file to a temporal folder, if it does not exist the pipeline is canceled

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
     sourceFolder: '$(projectPath)\myconfigfile.xml' 
     contents: '**/*' 
  targetFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'
  displayName: 'If file not exist, pipeline is cancel'
```