# Azure custom task visibleRule definition error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

When trying to update a custom task's version I get this error:

> Task definition visible rule 'serviceType = A || serviceType = B || ((serviceType = C || serviceType = D) && deploymentMode = Docker)' is invalid. It should be of format "A <validconditionhere> B"

What is the correct syntax for the visible rule to make the equivalent condition above?

Comment: Don't think it supports `( ... )`

Comment: @jessehouwing Then how can I have an equivalent condition to what I wrote in the question?

Comment: Not sure you can, you may have to change your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at [task samples](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fazure-pipelines-tasks+visiblerule&type=code),I am afraid that you can not use `( ...)`.It looks like expression conditions are somewhat limited.

I suggest to try the following based on these samples to avoid using `()` and see if this work for you.

```
"visibleRule": "serviceType = A || serviceType = B || serviceType = C && deploymentMode = Docker || serviceType = D && deploymentMode = Docker"
```